# Swift 3: UITapGestureRecognizer Not Firing

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I'm not sure why but my UITapGestureRecognizer is not firing correctly. Well in fact it is not firing at all. I am trying to get a function to run on the tap of an image.

Info about the setup:

- Not using storyboards, loading everything programmatically
- The view that I am loading this on also has a UICollectionView on it

ok so for the code:

The UIImageView is declared like so:

```
let backButtonIcon: UIImageView = {
    let bbi = UIImageView()
    bbi.image = UIImage(named: "backIcon")
    bbi.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    bbi.layer.zPosition = 2
    return bbi
}()
```

I then added that to the view:

```
view.addSubview(backButtonIcon)
```

to add the tap functionality to the UIImageView I am using:

```
let tapBackButton = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(backButtonPressed))
backButtonIcon.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
backButtonIcon.addGestureRecognizer(tapBackButton)
```

and lastly, here is the function that I am trying to run, just a simple print at the moment:

```
func backButtonPressed(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Go Back Pressed")
}
```

## Update:

I have already tried adding:

```
 bbi.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

and also:

```
backButtonIcon.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

## Update 2:

I created another blank view and used the code exactly as it is here and it worked.

Could it be something to do with the UICollectionView?

I made the UICollectionView zPosition -1 and the UIImageView zPosition at 1 but that alas that also did not work.

Comment: The selector doesn't seems correct, it should at least crash with a unrecognized selector. What's the superview of `backButtonIcon` exactly?

Comment: @Larme nope no crash. Why is it not correct?

Comment: I had an issue with a gestureRecognizer not working when I didn't maintain a reference (i.e. a variable) to the view that it was added to. Here's my SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144874/frontmost-uiview-with-tapgesturerecognizer-not-receiving-touches/40157112#40157112

Comment: Where in the life cycle are you adding the gesture recognizer? What order are you adding the subviews? Where/how are you setting out your layout constraints? More context may be helpful

Comment: @Brett apologies. So, the gesture recognizer is in the View Did load and the collectionview is in the ViewDidAppear. I have tried adding either one to the other but it still didnt work. I am rather new at Swift programming hence the lack of context, if you could let me know what to do and how to find out I can get that info for you :)

Comment: @Brett I do appreciate your help btw :)

Comment: Suggestion: I would add `bbi.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` and your tapGesture to the `backButtonIcon` closure. Keep everything in one place!

Comment: Also, the order of your view hierarchy may be the problem. Get rid of the zLayer positioning and add both subviews in viewDidLoad, collection view first then the image view.

Comment: @Nathaniel how would i do that? I am unable to to add bbi.addGestureRecognizer(tapBackButton) as computer says no

Comment: @JamesG What is the error? I just tried without any build errors

Comment: @Nathaniel there are no errors, it just isnt firing.

Comment: @JamesG You've also included the `isUserInteractionEnabled = true`?

Comment: yup. see update 1 of question

Answer (score 2):

Image views ignore user events by default. Normally, you use image views only to present visual content in your interface. If you want an image view to handle user interactions as well, change the value of its isUserInteractionEnabled property to true. After doing that, you can attach gesture recognizers or use any other event handling techniques to respond to touch events or other user-initiated events.

source: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimageview

Comment: Well it definitely would have been part of the solution so not sure why the down vote

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the UICollectionView, which is composed of UICollectionViewCells that already have a tap enabled by definition.

I'm looking through a very old app (Swift 1.x) I wrote for my personal usage (as in it never saw the light of day) and here's what I seemed to do - you probably need to do some variation of this:

- Subclassed UICollectionViewCell and added a UILabel and UIImageView as subviews to it, populating them (along with a NSURL for the tap action).
- Declared (and adopted) a specific UIViewController to also be my UICollectionView delegate (also for my purposes it was a SFSafariViewController delegate).
- In that VC's viewDidLoad() I *did* set up a long press (for removing) and double tap (for reloading) gestures, but **did not** set up a tap gesture - it isn't needed.
- In that VC's viewDidLoad() I loaded (and populated) the cells.

Here's the thing I think you are getting stuck on, but without more code I'm not sure:

- Coded against:

  ```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? BookmarkCell {
          selectedBookmarkSection = indexPath.section
          selectedBookmarkRow = indexPath.row
          sfc = SFSafariViewController(URL: cell.targetUrl!, entersReaderIfAvailable:true)
          sfc.delegate = self
          presentViewController(sfc, animated: true, completion: nil)
      } else {
          // Error indexPath is not on screen: this should never happen.
      }
  }
  ```

Please be kind, as this was something I wrote back in July 2014! (I update the collectionView(didSelectItemAt:indexPath:) for Swift 3.x but that's it.)

TR;DR: I think - particularly if your tap is seen outside of a UICollectionView - that this may get you working.